# Running nessu on Ubuntu on WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, nessus

I am unable to start nessus in WSL using:

```
/bin/systemctl start nessusd.service
```

I get the following error:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `sudo /opt/nessus/sbin/nessus-service`.  Systemd is not available in WSL2, so you need to use the older init-style scripts when available.

Comment: And what's your experience? does it then really run and do it's job?